# solr: multivalued geospatial search - returning closest point

Tags: lucene, solr, geospatial

Is there a way in Solr to have a document that:

- contains multiple lat/long pairs
- ask to return the closest point to a given (user-supplied) lat/long pair
- sort/filter based on that 'closest point'.

I was looking at:

- http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearchDev
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2155 (which talks about multivalued points)

But not sure if that would give me what I want.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future ref:

Use experimental Lucene Spatial Playground, 
For detailed use-case and solution see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2155?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=13114703#comment-13114703